# How to get the facebook user id to another javascript file after login?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I understand that I can get the facebook id by doing:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your id is ' + response.id);
});
```

However, I want to have the user login and then grab that id in a different file so I can handle it. Right now I have:

```
var id = "";
var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "?callback=?"

$(function(){
    $("#fb-profile-picture")[0].src = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id +"/picture";

    $.getJSON(fburl, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#name").append(data.name);
        $("#user-id").append(data.id);
    });

});
```

and if I manually enter the `id` in the `id` var it works however I'd like to be able to grab that `response.id`as the value and use it in this other javascript file but I haven't figured out how to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you

- cannot control which of the scripts is executed first
- you are working in an environment with a global window object
- part one is only executed once
- you are using jQuery

making a global and firing an event might be a solution, although not considered best practice.

Script 1:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  window.fbCustomId = response.id;
  console.log(window.fbCustomId);
  $(window).trigger('fbResponseLoaded');
});
```

Script 2:

```
function renderProfile() {
    var fburl = "//graph.facebook.com/" + window.fbCustomId + "?callback=?"

    $(function () {
        $("#fb-profile-picture")[0].src = "//graph.facebook.com/" + window.fbCustomId + "/picture";

        $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
            console.log(data, window.fbCustomId);
            $("#name").append( $('<span>').text(data.name) );
            $("#user-id").append( $('<span>').text(data.id) );
        });

    });
}
if (window.fbCustomId) {
    renderProfile();
} else {
    $(window).on('fbResponseLoaded', renderProfile);
}
```

Comment: this solves the issue of passing the info however the object `data` shows an error now:`Object {error: Object}`any idea why?

Comment: this solves the issue of passing the info however the object `data` shows an error now:`Object {error: Object}`any idea why? The error is happening because the ID from window.fbId is different than my user ID but no idea why.It's giving me a much larger number.

Comment: And `error.message` is? Take a debugger and console that allows you inspecting objects like latest versions of Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I; IE F12; Firefox, Opera Ctrl+Shift+I

Comment: yes, I'm inspecting it and that's what I get, if I open it it is: `Object {error: Object}
error: Object
__proto__: Object``